# Hibernate Example.create does not work with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I have this situation;
Postgres table:

```
   Colonna   |         Tipo          | Modificatori 
-------------+-----------------------+--------------
 id_followee | character varying(20) | non null
 id_follower | character varying(20) | non null
 attivo      | boolean               | 
 valutazione | boolean               | non null
Indici:
    "seguaci_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_followee, id_follower)
```

Therefore, I created a pojo class that uses a @EmbeddedId, in this way:

```
@Embeddable
public class SeguaciId implements java.io.Serializable {
    // Fields
        @Column(name = "id_followee", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String idFollowee;
    @Column(name = "id_follower", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String idFollower;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "seguaci", schema = "public")
public class Seguaci extends Pojo implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1862253468007580073L;
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "idFollowee", column = @Column(name = "id_followee", nullable = false, length = 20)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "idFollower", column = @Column(name = "id_follower", nullable = false, length = 20)) })
    private SeguaciId id; // not null
    @Column(name = "attivo")
    private Boolean attivo;
    @Column(name = "valutazione", nullable = false)
    private Boolean valutazione; // not null
}
```

At this point, I noticed that the method

```
org.hibernate.criterion.Example.create()
```

does not consider the values entered in the object embedded.
For example

```
SeguaciDAO dao = new SeguaciDAO();
    Seguaci se = new Seguaci();
    se.setAttivo(true);
    SeguaciId id = new SeguaciId();
    id.setIdFollowee("stefano");
    se.setId(id);

// end call this method
List<Seguaci> results = this.getSession().createCriteria(Seguaci.class)
                    .add( Example.create(instance) )
                    .list();
```

I expect a query like
*select * from seguaci where id_folloee = 'stefano' and attivo = true;*
but, I obtain only one condition in the where

```
where (this_.attivo=?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate documentation [states](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples) that query by example (QBE) **ignores** the primary key:

> Version properties, identifiers and associations are ignored. By
>   default, null valued properties are excluded.

You need to add identifier restriction **manually** with *.add(Restrictions.eq(...))*:

```
List<Seguaci> results = this.getSession().createCriteria(Seguaci.class)
                    .add( Example.create(instance) )
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("id.idFollowee", "stefano"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("id.idFollower", "Pierock"))
                    .list();
```